# How to unlock blank cells in workbook with VBA on open

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets that needs all non-blank cells to be locked and protected when opening the workbook.

This will be an employee training record where multiple trainers will be evaluating new staff on skills.  I would like to prevent anyone from accidentally deleting training data.

I found a code that will lock all cells, set all blank cells as unlocked, and protect the individual worksheet, but I'm having trouble applying this across my entire workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim myCell As Range

    Set myCell = Selection
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    myCell.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Locked = False

    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, _
      Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    myCell.Select

End Sub
```

Ideally, I would also like to add password protection to prevent a new employee from unprotecting the workbook.  Is this possible within the same code?  Can split this to a new question also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the password for each sheet is *secret*:

```
Sub Tony()
    Dim s As Worksheet

    For Each s In Sheets
        s.Unprotect ("secret")
            s.Cells.Locked = False
            On Error Resume Next
                s.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Locked = True
                s.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
            On Error GoTo 0
        s.Protect ("secret")
    Next s

End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

First make sure this does what you want.  Only then have your event macro call it.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Exactly what I needed